# shiduch date haircut during sefira

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, hair, mourning-aveilus, shidduchim-dating

Are you allowed to get a haircut during the Omer if you are going on a shiduch date?

Comment: Why would a "shidduch date" be special, as opposed to a "regular" date?

Answer (score 8):

*See* HALACHICALLY SPEAKING, [Customs During Sefira Part 11](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/weekly_torah.php?id=905):

> **Shaving for a date**
>
> One is not permitted to shave during his custom of sefira even if he has a date.(99)
>
> *(99)Harav Yisroel Belsky Shlita, see Piskei Shmuos pages 62-63 quoting the opinion of Harav Elyashiv Shlita.*

Comment: Interesting.  R' Moshe Feinstein allows getting a haircut during Sefira to attend a wedding (assuming the people making the wedding have a different Sefira custom).  I wonder what he'd say about this.

Comment: One interesting difference b/t a haircut and shaving is that it is not obvious when one last got a haircut, whereas it is clear that many people shave during sefirah, usually for business purposes. the girl would know for sure if you shaved, but may not notice a haircut.

Comment: Shalom, Where is the source for that P'sak from Rav Moshe?

Comment: @Shalom ^good question...

Comment: @Yahu It's definitely in Igros somewhere. I've seen it before.